# writing to file thread safe

Tags: swift, thread-safety

I have a function that appends data to a file by calling the following extension:

```
    extension Data {
        func append(fileURL: URL) throws {
            if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {
                defer {
                    fileHandle.closeFile()
                }
                fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                fileHandle.write(self)
            }
            else {
                try write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            }
        }
    }
    func appendToFile(text:String, url:URL) {
        let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        try data.append(fileURL: url)
    }
```

Now this function is called multiple times within `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {...}` Could this be a problem if the function is called another time while it's still writing? If so, how do I make it thread-safe?

Comment: I recommend you to use actor.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a problem if this is called from multiple threads at the same time, they can overwrite each other's content. You need to encapsulate it in some way and ensure only one thread is accessing the file at the same time.

There's countless ways to solve this, from very simple to highly sophisticated:

- Simply introduce a serial queue and ensure all these operations are always dispatched to that queue. Depending on your needs this is probably the easiest way to solve this.
- Write an actor that manages all those file accesses. If you're targeting iOS versions not supporting Swift `async`/`await`, it's not an option, of course.
- Go fancy: Write a dedicated object, maybe singleton, that can manage those operations and allows concurrent access to different URLs but ensures the same URL is only accessed serially, via queue or mutex.

Comment: sorry i don't understand much of what you're suggesting. I have very few experience with async. If i understand it right, writing a function `func appendLine(line:String) async {...}`and using always that to write would solve the problem, but it seems like i can't call `await appendLine("...")` inside a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async`

Comment: No, `async` alone will not solve the problem as it still allows multiple threads to run it at the same time. Using an `actor` (and ensuring that the same actor instance is used everywhere) would solve it. But frankly, the easiest way for you is to create a [serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init) (leave `attributes:` argument empty) and make sure to always dispatch your file access to this queue (it must exist only once).